# .on() not working in .fn jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have jquery function like this :

```
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.LazyImageLoad = function() { 

        $(this).on('scroll load resize' , function() {

            console.log ( 'Lazy Image Load run' )

            $('img' , this).each(function() {
                 $(this).hide(1000) ;
            });

        });

    }

})( jQuery );
```

and set this fucntion on my element for example

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).LazyImageLoad();
    $('body').LazyImageLoad();
    $('.Container_C2').LazyImageLoad();

});
```

but `$(this).on()` not work on `.fn jquery function`
and `console.log` and `$(img).show() for each` img not run ,

so what would u guy suggest me to do ?

Comment: where is following code : `$(img).show()`. Are you missing some piece of code?

Comment: Describe not working because you are binding some events not handled by some elements. And FYI, `this` is already jQuery object in prototype jq.fn method

Answer (score 1):

You have typo error in `consloe.log`. It should be `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

if vijayP answer doesn't work, try :

```
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.LazyImageLoad = function() { 

        $(this).on('scroll' , function() {
            doMyStuff(this);
        });
        $(this).on('load' , function() {
            doMyStuff(this);
        });
        $(this).on('resize' , function() {
            doMyStuff(this);
        });

    }

    function doMyStuff(this)
    {
        console.log ( 'Lazy Image Load run' )

        $('img' , this).each(function() {
            $(this).hide(1000) ;
        });
    }

})( jQuery );
```